# Creating Dataframe which uses BigInteger throws scala.MatchError: class java.math.BigInteger (of class java.lang.Class)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Spark Version : 1.3

I have a requirement where in I'm dealing with `BigInteger` type data. The Bean Class (Pojo) uses few `BigInteger` data-types. Parsing of the data and creating `JavaRDD` works fine, but when creating a dataframe which takes the JavaRDD and a BeanClass as a parameter,Spark throws below exception.

```
scala.MatchError: class java.math.BigInteger (of class java.lang.Class)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$getSchema$1.apply(SQLContext.scala:1182)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$getSchema$1.apply(SQLContext.scala:1181)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.getSchema(SQLContext.scala:1181)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.createDataFrame(SQLContext.scala:419)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.createDataFrame(SQLContext.scala:447)
```

Using Spark-Shell I see that Scala is able to handle BigInt

```
scala> val x = BigInt("190753000000000000000");

x: scala.math.BigInt = 190753000000000000000
```

I'm not sure what is the reason for the Exception. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Issue raised https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11827

Answer (score 1):

Following up to @zero232's answer, your exception may be resolved by using `BigDecimal` instead of `BigInt` in your variable declaration:

```
scala> val x = BigDecimal("190753000000000000000");
```

Answer (score 0):

You get an exception because `BigInt` is not a supported data type for Spark `DataFrames`. The only `Big*` type supported is a `BigDecimal`.

You'll find a full list of supported types and mappings in a [Data Types section](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#data-types) of the [Spark SQL and DataFrame Guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to memSQL's BigInt UserDefinedType :

```
    package com.memsql.spark.connector.dataframe

    import org.apache.spark.sql.types._


    @SQLUserDefinedType(udt = classOf[BigIntUnsignedType])
    class BigIntUnsignedValue(val value: Long) extends Serializable {
      override def toString: String = value.toString
    }

    /**
     * Spark SQL [[org.apache.spark.sql.types.UserDefinedType]] for MemSQL's `BIGINT UNSIGNED` column type.
     */
    class BigIntUnsignedType private() extends UserDefinedType[BigIntUnsignedValue] {
      override def sqlType: DataType = LongType

      override def serialize(obj: Any): Long = {
        obj match {
          case x: BigIntUnsignedValue => x.value
          case x: String       => x.toLong
          case x: Long         => x
        }
      }

      override def deserialize(datum: Any): BigIntUnsignedValue = {
        datum match {
          case x: String => new BigIntUnsignedValue(x.toLong)
          case x: Long => new BigIntUnsignedValue(x)
        }
      }

      override def userClass: Class[BigIntUnsignedValue] = classOf[BigIntUnsignedValue]

      override def asNullable: BigIntUnsignedType = this

      override def typeName: String = "bigint unsigned"
    }

    case object BigIntUnsignedType extends BigIntUnsignedType
```